# Android Password Validation

Tags: java, android, regex

I am developing an Android application where in i have to validate the password. Below are the code lines which i have used for validation but yet I could not get the required validation.

My Requirement is: A string need to be parsed such that it takes at least one special character, one digit and any alphabets from A-Z,a-z .. Please help me in getting the required output..

```
public static boolean isAlphaNumericPwd(String name) {
        return name.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
    }

    public static boolean isSpecialPwd(String name) {
        return name.matches("!@#$*()?,.");
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Your regex would not work for what you are attempting to do.  First i'll point out the issue and then below I'll show you what you should be doing:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
```

This above regex looks for an entire string where only the letters (capital & lowercase) a-z exist and/or numbers exist.  Because you are using the start and end anchors (^ - start anchor, $ - end anchor) you are saying that the ENTIRE password must contain ONLY those values.  Substrings will not be considered a match because of those anchors.

The regex you are using for checking special characters also will not work, because you are not escaping reserved regex characters, and even if you were this would look for ONLY the pattern `!@#*()?,.` in that order within a substring.

The * character is reserved for zero or more occurrence of the previous character (#).  The character `?` is reserved to represent zero or one of the prior character, so you're checking that ) may or may not exist.  Then the . character means ANY character.  If you did want this exact expression you'd need to escape it as such:

```
"!@#$\*()\?,\."
```

However, that still would not solve your issue because it's going to match that set of characters, IN THAT ORDER.

It sounds like you just want to check that there are letters, at least one number, and at least one special character.  In this case you cannot use only a single regular expression...that is if you want to use regex for this.

```
public static boolean validatePassword(String pswd) {
    //check that there are letters
    if(!pswd.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
        return false;  //nope no letters, stop checking and fail!            
    //check if there are any numbers
    if(!pswd.matches("[0-9]+"))
        return false;  //nope no numbers, stop checking and fail!
    //check any valid special characters
    if(!pswd.matches("[.!#*()?,]+"))
        return false;  //nope no special chars, fail!

    //everything has passed so far, lets return valid
    return true;
}
```

Notice in my example that each expression does not contain any anchors.  This is because we don't care where the characters are in the string, just that they exist.  I also did NOT used the `*` because that can potentially mean zero, but instead used the `+` character, since this means AT LEAST once.  Finally note that all of these are placed in brackets, this means that they are character classes so we want one character that matches any of those values.  The `+` then works on the character class as a whole, instead of a single character.  Additionally, within a character class you do not need to escape (most) reserved characters, because they have different (or no) meaning within that construct.

With that all being said be aware that these are not good password requirements, but this should at least point you in the right direction on how you would go about this validation method.